# longest increasing subarray in recursive method using python

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

I tried solving this problem without recursion method

```
def findLongest():
    nums=[1, 9, 3, 10, 4, 20, 2]
    f = c = lastMax = p1 = 0

    while (p1 < len(nums) - 1):
        p2 = p1 + 1
        while (p2 < len(nums) - 1):
            if nums[p2] > nums[p1]:
                c += 1
                if f == 0:
                    f = 1
                    p1 = p2
            p2 += 1

        if c > lastMax:
            lastMax = c
            f = 0
            c = 0
        p1 += 1
    return lastMax
```

I have searched the web quite a bit to find a nice and easy recursion method to understand.

Comment: Are you trying to find the length of the longest sequence within the list that is in increasing order?  Your code produces 3, whereas the right answer is 2.

Comment: Yes that’s what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finds the length of the longest monotonically increasing subsequence in the list.  This is not a problem that lends itself to a recursive solution.

```
def findLongest(nums):
    last = 99999999
    maxSeq = 0
    for n in nums:
        if n > last:
            seq += 1
            if seq > maxSeq:
                maxSeq = seq
        else:
            seq = 1
        last = n
    return maxSeq
print( findLongest([1, 9, 3, 10, 4, 20, 2]))
```

Here is a recursive version.

```
def find1(last, nums, n):
    if nums and nums[0] > last:
        return find1(nums[0], nums[1:], n+1 )
    else:
        return n

def findRecursive(nums):
    maxseq = 0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        n = find1(nums[i], nums[i+1:], 1)
        if n > maxseq:
            maxseq = n
    return maxseq

print( findRecursive([1, 9, 3, 10, 4, 20, 2]))
```

Comment: Thanks it works ..  why can this problem not be done recursively? I found this link but honestly dont understand it https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/102232/calculating-longest-increasing-sub-sequence-recursively

Comment: I didn't say it couldn't be done, I said it isn't natural, which is exactly what the commenter said in that link.  It makes way more sense as an iterative solution.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I see how the recursion method just doesn't seem natural.